# How to create seperate collection on seperate web page in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, collections, router

I am creating a DB for my website where people can enter their Name and Message . In my “www.mydomainname.com/USA” page the message is same as it is on the “www.mydomainname/Germany” page . When i add a Name and Message in “/Germany” page the message will be added on both "/germany" and  “/USA” page and vice versa.Is there is any way where i write message and that message will be on that same page not in other page of my website ?

Should I have to create a separate collection and if i create it do i have to create the collection of every 190 countries ?
Please Help Me …!

Comment: Why don't you just add a `country` field to your schema? Like `{ country : "us" }` or `{ country : "de" }`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three common approaches

### Separate databases

You create one database for each site. That makes sense if all or most data is "per site"

### Separate collections

You use one database and create one collection for each site. That makes sense if most data should be shared and just this piece should be always separated.

### "Site" property

You add a property to your documents that stores the site

```
{
   message: "example",
   site: "USA"
}
```

Now you can filter the collection and show messages for all sites or just a single site.